# How to use STR_TO_DATE with JPA specification to order by dates with a string datatype

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot application with get API which exact the records from the database based on the given filter options. To achieve that I am using the JPA specifications to build the query dynamically. Now I have the last modified date in the table based on which I need to order the records. As I have the varchar data type for last modified date which I cannot change as date or datetime I have to use the STR_TO_DATE function of MySQL database to order the records based on the date.

How can I create the below query using the JPA specifications with Spring Boot?

```
SELECT * FROM table-name ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(`LastModifiedDate`, '%Y-%m-%d') DESC;
```

Comment: Because you are using a database specific function you should mark the query as native. The query can be added as annotation to a JPARepository method. Say getSomethingSortedByDate.